# Using the map function, show map elements that each have an image

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display map elements using the map function of React.
Each map element has an image.
If I look at the array, there is content in this, so it is filled.
The picture is in Base64 format.
If I try to render a normal images tag with an image from the array outside of the map function, this is how it works!
So it must somehow be due to the map function - just where?

```
    {alleBilder.length &&
    alleBilder.map((bild, index) => {
      <Col md={3} xs={6}>
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardActionArea>
            <img src={bild.bild}></img>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                Lizard
              </Typography>
              <Typography
                variant="body2"
                color="textSecondary"
                component="p"
              >
                Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with
                over 6,000 species, ranging across all continents except
                Antarctica
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
          <CardActions style={{ float: "right" }}>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </Col>;
    })}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything inside the map function. You could add return like so: `return (<Col>...</Col>)` or substitute curly braces with normal one like so: `alleBilder.map((bild, index) => (<Col>...</Col>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're messing with the callback of `map`. You're supposed to return jsx from the callback but you're returning nothing. Please look at how to use the `map` in JSX:

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[How to use it in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

Equivalent to:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  (<li>{number}</li>)
);
```

equivalent to:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) => {
  return (<li>{number}</li>)
}
);
```